# Casting HLS crashes the app or makes it unstable and unusable

Tags: android, casting, exoplayer

The exoplayer version is 2.18.7
The exoplayer cast extension for casting the HLS stream to chromecast and mi androidtv  devices.
The Android operating system we have tested this on are 10, 11, 12, 13.
The demo-cast seems to be crashing upon casting start.

Tried to cast the HSL stream and was expecting the stream to start playing on my chromecast device, instead the app crashes or becomes unstable and the stream also is not starting on the tv.